# Share message to Facebook using ACTION_SEND

Tags: facebook, android-intent

As most of you know Facebook do not allow any text sent via 
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message) and using ACTION_SEND.

Any workarounds to achieve the task. ?

Comment: Prefilling message is not allowed anyway

Comment: What is your specific use case? As mentioned above, first of all prefilling is against policy. Secondly, there are variety of Android dialogs included with the recent versions of the Android SDK, meaning you do not need build your own intent.